# How to accelerate re-start of spring application in Tomcat?

Tags: java, file, tomcat, restart

I have a big spring application with more than 1000 libraries.
When I do debug frequently not possible only adjust changes without restart, but restart takes a long time (about 5 minutes.) But 1000 libraries remain the same, I have changed only a few rows of code. Is it possible in some way to say to tomcat to apply only classes that were changed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/). In most cases, you can avoid redeploys. It replaces the class without having to restart the container.

Note that I'm not attached to ZeroTurnaround, except as a happy user.